# How to deploy AWS Appconfig hosted configuration version via AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-ssm, aws-app-config

I have been following this document to create a hosted version in AppConfig via CLI.

Issue :
The `content` parameter in the aws command expects a strict type of *blob*. I want to upload a relative large yaml file of approx 40kB which is present in my code repo as the `content` which is of type blob.

What would be the ideal way to convert this yaml file to base64 and add to the `content` param all via CLI?

I manually tried to convert the yaml to base64 and add in the command but CLI couldn't handle that much data and didn't respond.

> Note : Using Powershell in VSCode Windows

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using PowerShell. If you are able to install the AWS CLI in your PowerShell environment, using `--content fileb://mylargefile.yaml` should allow you to upload your large YAML file as an AppConfig hosted configuration version. There is no need to do any Base64 conversion of your file before running the command.

Example

```bash
$ aws appconfig create-hosted-configuration-version \
    --application-id "yourid" \
    --configuration-profile-id "yourid" \
    --content-type text/plain \
    --region us-east-1 \
    --content fileb://mylargefile.yaml \
    configuration_version_output_file
{
    "ApplicationId": "yourid",
    "ConfigurationProfileId": "yourid",
    "VersionNumber": "1",
    "ContentType": "text/plain"
}
```

See [Best practices for local file parameters](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/best-practices-for-local-file-parameters/)